# Cannot paste code into Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I am trying to paste the sample code from the **Google script** tutorial into the **script editor** as instructed - but the code does not get transferred. I highlight the sample code, `right click & select copy, position on the Google script editor`, remove the existing code as instructed, right click and paste and nothing gets transferred.
To prove that the copy worked I pasted successfully into Notepad. Any ideas? I have `windows 7` `& IE11`.

Help!

Comment: Can you write something in the script editor?

Comment: Hi - yes it is possible to type directly into the script editor.

Comment: its because IE11. Use chrome. the apps script editor works best in chrome.

Comment: That's sorted it! (I wonder why?) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Some fields are designed to not accept paste data, you see that allot on register forms where you are forced to type in your email and password manually, maybe something like this is happening there.